# Copy selected images from subfolders, FOR cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Within a master folder I have 1000 folders all individially named with a part number such as DGTS-9045. Within that folder are various sub-folders, one of which contains 24 jpeg images (used for html5 product rotation sequences)

How would I copy say 6 images, such as frames 1,5,9,13,17 and 21 from within each of those 1000 sub-folders and place them in another folder named the same as the original? All original folders are stored locally on pc, destination folders would need to be created through the script.

I tried `for /d %1 in (*) do for %2 in (1,5,9,13,17, 21) do copy %1\photos\pic%2.jpg %1\newfolder` but got `The system cannot find the file specified`

If the images are in subfolders of `D:\Pictures\Client Name\2nd Batch, 21st March\Html 5 outputs` and they are to be copied to folders in `D:\Pictures\Selected` what would the correct syntax be?

Answer (score 0):

To see what might be a result of this nested `for` loops, try (copy and paste to command line and hit `<Enter>`)

```
for /d %g in (*) do @for %h in (1,5,9,13,17, 21) do @echo @copy %g\photos\pic%h.jpg %g\newfolder\
```

To get more info: try `for /?` and [read more](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) about `for` command, especially on recursing subfolders `for /R`.

Then you could get rid of `@echo` to run `@copy` commands for real...